# Posicionamiento absoluto CSS Asp.net MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Alguien sabe que es lo que pasa. 
La imagen (addf) con posición absoluta no respeta a su contenedor.

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <img src="~/Imagenes/addf.png" style="width:100%;height:auto;position:absolute"/>
</div>
```

La imagen de fondo debería tener un tamaño de 100x100px
[image: La imagen de fondo debería tener un tamaño de 100x100px]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Alguien sabe que es lo que pasa?

Lo que pasa **es que cuando usas un elemento con posición absoluta, tienes que declararle al padre que va a ser el elemento referente** (para el tamaño y posicionamiento), sino el elemento con posición absoluta va a tomar como referente el tamaño total de la ventana o viewport o el ancestro que si definas como referente.

Basta con que **agregues al elemento contenedor un position: relative**, así:

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; position: relative;">
    <img src="~/Imagenes/addf.png" style="width:100%; height:auto; position:absolute; "/>
</div>
```

Se que no lo preguntaste y tus motivos has de tener, pero es mejor que para darle estilos a los elementos uses clases en un archivo css externo que asignes a cada etiqueta, así:

```
.contenedor-imagen{
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.contenedor-imagen .imagen-contenida
/*o simplemente .contenedor-imagen img*/
{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto; 
  position: absolute;
}
```

Así solo tienes que agregar esta clase a cada etiqueta html que necesite que cumpla la función de contenedor de imágenes y no repites a lo loco código innecesariamente. Ejemplo:

```
<div class="contenedor-imagen">
    <img src="~/Imagenes/addf.png" class="imagen-contenida"/>
</div>
```

Comment: voy a probar,  gracias por tu ayuda.